# Which is faster among MySQL Community Server, Percona and MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, percona

I have a small setup of MySQL Community Server version 5.6 running on KVM based VPS. 4 CPU cores are available and total memory is limited to 1GB. I use MyISAM tables mainly for Wordpress and few other personal projects.

Which server can best suit my requirements among MySQL Community Server(all 5.x versions), Percona and MariaDB? I am basically looking for better performance (mainly read) and resource utilization.

Comment: How big (in GB) is the total size of the databases that your instance is going to have? You could do tests to drain the last drop of efficiency by choosing the mysql flavour that plays better in your setup but raising the (low for today's standards) memory would be a safer bet for improving efficiency.

Comment: Wih MyISAM you gain nothing using Percona because XtraDB is an InnoDB replacement. And @ypercube is correct. 1GB is pointless and I doubt you'll use 4 cores anyway

Comment: @ypercube Database size is well within 1GB, it is comparatively smaller setup and memory is just sufficient at the moment.

Comment: @gbn What about those extra performance optimizations in MariaDB 5.5 and 10? Won't that help much with smaller data size and less no. of CPU cores?

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this benchmark results:

https://blog.mariadb.org/benchmarking-mariadb-5-3-4/

The conclusion here was that MySQL-5.5 is the mos performing among others.

The tested editions here are :

- MariaDB-5.3.4 – the Monty Program release candidate, both with XtraDB
  and the InnoDB plugin
- Percona-Server 5.1.61 because it is based on the same XtraDB
  version as MariaDB-5.3
- Percona-Server 5.5.20 – the current Percona flagship
- MySQL-5.5.20 – the current Oracle flagship

Hope i helped

Comment: Well, that benchmark was done on a real server (with unknown amount of memory) - so it may or rather may not correspond the OP's setup.

Comment: The current Oracle flagship is 5.6 I think. And MariaDB has release (as GA, not RC) both 5.3 and 5.5 versions.

Comment: Helpful information @Audley-Christians. Appreciate if you can share information on latest releases because I also heard MySQL 5.6 is a better performer compared to 5.5 or older.